# infinite scroll knockout multiple requests

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I would like to use an infinite scroll on my html page. I don't know why I have multiples server answers...

```
$(window).data('jsonpready', true).scroll(function (e) {
     if ($(window).data('jsonpready') == false) return;

     if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 100) {
         // $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').show();
         $(window).data('jsonpready', false);
         viewModel.ui.FlashbackReport.MoreContacts();
         console.info("data loading");
         if (viewModel.ui.dataAvailable) {
             $(window).data('jsonpready', true);
         }

     }
 });
```

Function for server request which call mapping function later : `viewModel.ui.FlashbackReport.MoreContacts();`

`if(viewModel.ui.dataAvailable)`  to test if mapping is finished

Answer (score 0):

Here I found a beautiful implementation of this. http://jsfiddle.net/8x4vG/2/

```
    ko.bindingHandlers.scroll = {

  updating: true,

  init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
      var self = this
      self.updating = true;
      ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function() {
            $(window).off("scroll.ko.scrollHandler")
            self.updating = false
      });
  },

  update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor){
    var props = allBindingsAccessor().scrollOptions
    var offset = props.offset ? props.offset : "0"
    var loadFunc = props.loadFunc
    var load = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
    var self = this;

    if(load){
      element.style.display = "";
      $(window).on("scroll.ko.scrollHandler", function(){
        if(($(document).height() - offset <= $(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop())){
          if(self.updating){
            loadFunc()
            self.updating = false;
          }
        }
        else{
          self.updating = true;
        }
      });
    }
    else{
        element.style.display = "none";
        $(window).off("scroll.ko.scrollHandler")
        self.updating = false
    }
  }
 }

var viewModel = function(){            
this.collection = ko.observableArray([]) 
var disney = ["Mickey", "Donald", "Daffy", "Hewie", "Dewie", "Lewie"]
var self = this;
this.addSome = function(){ 

    for(var i = 0; i < 40; i++){
    self.collection.push(disney[Math.floor((Math.random()*6))]) 
        }
}

this.addSome()

}


ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that code isn't licensed by the author :(  I found this instead: https://github.com/thinkloop/knockout-js-infinite-scroll, MIT licensed.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm really late in asking this question. I was wondering who fires `scroll.ko.scrollHandler`? Is it related to knockout core or some thirdparty lib ?

Comment: $(window).on("scroll") is a jQ event and is fired by jQ. above script is trying to be more descriptive of the event by namespacing it with .ko.scrollHandler
so it doesn't get mixed up with potentially other actors who may be interested in the jQ scroll event. You can add whatever after an event name with a dot. $(window).on("scroll.foo.bar")